# Cant import tensorflow_model_optimization

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tfmot

I got an error when try to import the `tensorflow_model_optimization` package
When i run:

```
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot
```

I got the following ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Asura\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow_model_optimization\__init__.py", line 86, in <module>
from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.api import clustering
File "C:\Users\Asura\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow_model_optimization\python\core\api\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.api import clustering
File "C:\Users\Asura\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow_model_optimization\python\core\api\clustering\__init__.py", line 16, in 
<module>
from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.api.clustering import keras
File "C:\Users\Asura\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow_model_optimization\python\core\api\clustering\keras\__init__.py", line 19, 
in <module>
from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.clustering.keras.cluster import cluster_scope
File "C:\Users\Asura\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow_model_optimization\python\core\clustering\keras\cluster.py", line 20, in 
<module>
from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.clustering.keras import cluster_wrapper
File "C:\Users\Asura\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow_model_optimization\python\core\clustering\keras\cluster_wrapper.py", line 
24, in <module>
from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.clustering.keras import clustering_registry
File "C:\Users\Asura\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow_model_optimization\python\core\clustering\keras\clustering_registry.py", 
line 57, in <module>
class ClusteringRegistry(object):
File "C:\Users\Asura\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow_model_optimization\python\core\clustering\keras\clustering_registry.py", 
line 92, in ClusteringRegistry
tf.keras.experimental.PeepholeLSTMCell,
AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras.experimental' has no attribute 'PeepholeLSTMCell'
```

I have this error on different OS-es and with different python versions.
I suspect it is a version error of some of the tf packages.
The versions I use:

```
tensorflow                    2.9.1
tensorflow-addons             0.16.1
tensorflow-estimator          2.9.0
tensorflow-hub                0.12.0
tensorflow-io                 0.23.1
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.23.1
tensorflow-model-optimization 0.7.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I successfully imported `tensorflow_model_optimization` in my environment having the following versions:

```
tensorflow                    2.8.2
tensorflow-addons             0.17.1
tensorflow-estimator          2.8.0
tensorflow-hub                0.12.0
tensorflow-io                 0.26.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.26.0
tensorflow-model-optimization 0.7.3
```

Related to Tensorflow I have the additional packages:

```
tensorflow-datasets           4.0.1 
tensorflow-gcs-config         2.8.0  
tensorflow-metadata           1.9.0
tensorflow-probability        0.16.0
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed the tensorflow_model_optimization library first

```
pip install tensorflow_model_optimization
```

then run :

```
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfomt
```

also make sure to upgrade keras version

```
pip install --upgrade keras
```